# How to forbid creation of two class objects with the same parameters?

Tags: java

friends and colleagues. I have following class:

```
public class Department {
private String departmentName;
private int moneyForDepartment;

public Department(String departmentName, int moneyForDepartment){
    if (moneyForDepartment < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid value");
    }
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
    this.moneyForDepartment = moneyForDepartment;
}

public Department(){

}

public String getDepartmentName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public int getMoneyForDepartment() {
    return moneyForDepartment;
}

public void setMoneyForDepartment(int moneyForDepartment) {
    this.moneyForDepartment = moneyForDepartment;
}
```

}

and for example i will create two objects of this class:

```
Department dep1 = new Department("Storage", 100000);
Department dep2 = new Department("Storage", 200000);
```

Please tell me how can i forbid to create class object in case when object of this class with the same first parameter is already exists ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to do that globally across your entire application (in static state), because then testing becomes difficult.  Instead, create a factory for your `Department` class, maybe looking something like this:

```
public class Department {
  private Department(String departmentName, int moneyForDepartment) { ... }
  ...
  public static class Factory {
     private Set<String> seenDepartmentNames = new HashSet<>();
     public Department create(String departmentName, int moneyForDepartment) {
        if (!seenDepartmentNames.add(departmentName)) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Department already created");
        }
        return new Department(departmentName, moneyForDepartment);
     }
  }
}
```

This forces all construction to go through the `Factory`, since the `Department` constructor is private.  Just use one `Factory` across your application, and you can still create new ones for testing without running into problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static field in the `Department` class and keep a `Set` with the department names already used:

```
public class Department {
    private static final Set<String> usedDepartmentNames = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

Then, in the constructor, do:

```
public Department(String departmentName, int moneyForDepartment) {
    if (usedDepartmentNames.contains(departmentName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Department already exists");
    }
    if (moneyForDepartment < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid value");
    }
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
    this.moneyForDepartment = moneyForDepartment;
    usedDepartmentNames.add(departmentName);
}
```